# Javascript Error after using Script Manager- : The message received from the server could not be parsed

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am opening a ShowModalDialog on a button OnClientClick event and the javascript for it is:-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function openmodalWinLunch() {
            var variable1 = "Lunch";
            window.showModalDialog("ClockPopUP.aspx?code=" + variable1, "dialogWidth:290px;dialogHeight:270px,");
        }
```

On the Clock.aspx page i have a asp button on which i had written code :-

```
protected void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _nonProduction = new NonProduction();
        if (Session["LastNonProdTimeID"] == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            int NonProdTimeEntryID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LastNonProdTimeID"]);
            //Updating the TimeSpent 
            isTimeSpentUpdated = _nonProduction.UpdateTimeSpentInDB(NonProdTimeEntryID);
            if (isTimeSpentUpdated == true)
            {

                string timespent = Convert.ToString(_nonProduction.GetTimeSpent(NonProdTimeEntryID));
                //string msg = "Total time consumed  in " +HiddenTaskname.Value.ToString()+": " + timespent.ToString() + " Minutes";
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.close();</script>");
                Response.End();

            }
            else
            {
            }
        }



    }
```

Preveously every thing is working fine and this code is working as per my requirement. Just i had added Scriptmanager on the Clock.aspx as i m showing a clock which shows the elapsed time to the user. After that when i m clicking on the btn_Stop on CLock.aspx page i am getting this error message:-"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed."

Please guide me that how i solve this issue.

I found that what is the root cause of this error. It is happening because i m using Resonse.Write and other information is  [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx)

Guide me that how i fix this as i want to close the webpage after button click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had Used

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "CLOSE", "window.close();", true);`

in place of

`Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.close();</script>");
                Response.End();`
and this helps me to fix the error.